# jQuery: Clear input field if it is not filled in certain time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, time

Using jquery or js, how can I clear an input field if it doesn't reach x amount of characters in a certain time?

Basically, if an input field doesn't reach 10 characters in 1 second, I want to clear any input that was typed.

How can I calculate the time from start of typing (1st character input) to reaching the 10th character?

Comment: ... sounds like very hectic input form to me ;-) good luck!

Comment: Is `blur` event okay for you? As said by @cars10, it would be un-comfortable for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should link it to the `keyup` event like here:

```
// ... somewhere in the ON DOM READY section, input has ID "a"
$('#a').keyup(function(){var o=$(this);// o: jQuery object referring to the current input
                         setTimeout(function(){ if (o.val().length<5) o.val('');},1000);
})
```

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/1fjyezf7/ . I reduced the minimum length to 5 characters in the example. My typing is too slow otherwise ;-).

Comment: This does the job. About the typing speed, I'm actually making use a barcode scanner so that's pretty quick :P

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `onfocus` event and `setTimeout`.

```js
document.getElementById("test").onfocus = function(){
    setTimeout(function(th){
        if(th.value.length <10){//If the no. of characters is less than 10 then clear the input field
         th.value = '';
        }
    }, 1000, this)//Time set is 1 second
}
```

```html
<input id="test"/>
```